# How can i use methods in c#?

Tags: c#, xcode, methods

So, I have to do homework about methods in c#.  I am confused about some points. I wrote methods (they may be wrong) but I don't know how to call them. How can I write this part? For example finding max value. What can I write? I tried a lot of times but couldn't handle it.

Also, this code has to be kept in a txt file but doesn't.

```
    public static void WriteData(StreamWriter sw)
    {
        int[,] a = new int[4, 6];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int J = 0; J < a.GetLength(1); J++)
            {
                a[i, J] = rnd.Next(10, 100);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nMATRIX:");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int J = 0; J < a.GetLength(1); J++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,-4}", a[i, J]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nTRANSPOSE:");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            for (int J = 0; J < a.GetLength(0); J++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,-4}", a[J, i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public static void DisplayMatrix(int[,] a) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
    }


    public static int MaxNumber(int[] a)
    {
        int max = a[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            if (max < a[i])
            { max = a[i]; }
        }
        return max;
     }   

    public static void DisplayOddOrEvenForMax(int max)
    {
        if (max % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number is even");

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Number is odd");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("MyMatrix.txt", true);
        WriteData(sw);
        sw.Close();
        `
```

Comment: Ask smaller question, not so many at a time.

Comment: Okay. I will do next time.

Comment: If the method returns a value, you can write `int maxOfA = MaxNumber(a);`. Your code is in a text file with the extension `.cs`. It has to be `.cs` to enable Visual Studio to recognize it as a C# file.

Comment: Why not this time ? Replace your "Console" with "sw" for instance, if you want to write to the StreamWriter - not to the Console.
And you have an two-dimensional array[4,6] but your Max function is for one-dimensional array only. So you have to adapt you max-function. You know how to loop over two dimensions from initialization with rnd.

Comment: I tried everything I can do. Have so many shortcomings. When I change something, program gives me a lot of errors. Can't find how to replace code to an other. Thank you for all of these.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are (usually) either attached to a class or are static

if you have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    void myMethod() {
       //do something
    }
}
```

then you have to create an instance of that class , so something like this:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass() //here foo is the name of the instance
```

and then call that method on that instance

```
foo.myMethod()
```

if the method is static like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static void myMethod() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

then that method does can be run directly by calling it, along with the class that contains it, so something like this:

```
MyClass.myMethod()
```

I hope this helped

Comment: I have tired these methods but program gave errors again. Thank you for your help.